Google Cloud Run with domain mapping and redirection to www/non-www
App is running on Google Cloud Run with domain mapping (example.com).
Now I need it should be works www.example.com too.
Questions:

So I should add another domain mapping with www. to the same container and also add CNAME record to ghs.google.com.
But this it's not redirect. And I think, for SEO will be marked as "Duplicate content".

Or maybe just add CNAME record from www to example.com without additional domain mapping. But I don't know if it should be works.

The same questions it concern to http to https.


Summarizing:
http://example.com.
http://www.example.com
https://www.example.com
should redirect to https://example.com

For these types of stuff, redirecting www to apex domain and redirecting http to https, it can be achieved via DNS provider.
For example, if you are using Cloudflare, you can make the follwing redirect rules.
Redirect www to apex
When incoming requests match
  Wildcard pattern
    Request URL: https://www.*
Then
  Target URL: https://${1}
  Status code: 301
  Preserve query string: Enabled

Redirect http to https
If incoming requests match: 
  Wildcard pattern
    Request URL: http://*
Then:
  Target URL: https://${1}
  Status code: 301
  Preserve query string: Enabled

The actual implementation might vary depending on your DNS provider.
References:

https://developers.cloudflare.com/rules/url-forwarding/examples/redirect-www-to-root/
https://developers.cloudflare.com/rules/reference/page-rules-migration/#migrate-always-use-https

